# Mapping in rxjs only adding new items not removing old

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a block of code that if the Api request has a needRefresh boolean it will call to the server and map the new data to the cached set. As is it will map new items from the server to the cached set but if you remove items from the server they won't be removed from the cached set. How do I fix this rxjs?

```
if (needsRefresh) {
            console.log('refreshed');
            let firstRun = true;
            return Observable.if(
                () => {
                    if (firstRun) {
                        firstRun = false;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                //this is the mapping code probably where the problem is
                this.requestSet(key, where).switchMap(() => this._cachedSets.get(key)),
                this._cachedSets.get(key)
            );
        }
        else {
            return this._cachedSets.get(key);
        }
```

Comment: You will need to have server to client side communication if you want to get notified on server changes.

Comment: @CozyAzure not the most intelligent comment I've seen.

Comment: I mean, that's technically how you would do it, or else how do you get notified on server changes? Alternatively, you can keep polling the server every x seconds and compare it with your `cachedSets`.

Comment: @CozyAzure Who said anything, like at all, about 'getting notified' about server changes? I'm talking about when you make an explicit call to the API the cachedsets is only being updated with new values but not removing the values from the cache that no longer exist on the server.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding your question completely.